# Does super work only with methods

Tags: objective-c

Being new to objectiveC I was experimenting with the super keyword. I wanted to know if the super keyword is only used for calling the base class method.
Consider the following code

```
@interface foo_base : NSObject
{
    int int_ivar;
}
-(void) base_method;
-(void) shared_method;
@end


@interface foo_der : foo_base
-(void) der_method;
-(void) shared_method;
@end
```

In the implementation of `shared_method` if I try doing this

```
@implementation foo_der
- (void) shared_method
{
     [super shared_method];  //Works ok call base class method
     int_ivar =23;           //Works ok (Access base class ivar)
     self->int_ivar = 23;    //Works ok (Access base class ivar)
     super->int_ivar=23;     //Error- Why ? is super only limited to methods?
}
...
...
@end
```

Is the super keyword only used for calling the base class methods from the derived class ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `super` is only for invoking methods. `super` is not really an object pointer. If it were, it would have the same pointer value as `self`. They refer to the same thing. It's just that `super` changes the lookup of the method implementation.

When you message `self`, the search for the implementation for the message you sent begins in the actual class of the object pointed to by `self`. That can be different than the static type of the `self` pointer.

When you message `super`, the search begins in the superclass of the class in whose implementation the message-to-`super` statement appears. That's the only purpose of `super`.